# What is the original Macintosh font?

Tags: fonts

[image]

Does anybody know what the font is in this picture? Thanks!

Comment: You may find this helpful http://www.storiesofapple.net/the-first-fonts-of-the-macintosh.html

Answer (score 17):

The font you are looking for is Chicago. Specially designed for early Apple Mac operating systems.

https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Chicago_(typeface)

Comment: @user8300: if this answered your question, you may want to [click that checkmark](https://graphicdesign.stackexchange.com/help/someone-answers).

Answer (score 2):

This is Apple's early proprietary screen font. It's obviously a bitmap font. Cut a piece of text, input it to Font Squirrel Matcherator and you get plenty of so good matches that it's difficult to select the closest. There are also some non-bitmap versions that resemble the screenshot. Here's one:

[image]